# Passing variable from console to vbs to Excel macro

Tags: c#, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to pass a variable down the following sets of code:

From a Console application written in `C#`:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {

    string myPath = @"R:\xxx\xxx\xxx\test.vbs";
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(myPath,"hello");
    p.StartInfo = ps;
    p.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Into the following `test.vbs` file:

```vb
strFolder = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
Set XL=CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
XL.Visible=True 
XL.Workbooks.Open "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\PassInVariable.xlsm",,True
XL.Run "'PassInVariable.xlsm'!xxx", strFolder   '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<PROBLEM SEEMS TO BE HERE
XL.Workbooks("PassInVariable.xlsm").close false
XL.quit
Set XL=nothing
```

Then in the `PassInVariable.xlsm` file I've got the following:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub xxx(x As String)

MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Seems like the variable `strFolder` in the `VBScript` file is the problem because if I replace this with a literal such as "hello" then the variable moves into the excel VBA.

How do I fix the vbs file so that the variable gets passed down the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables in VBScript are `Variant`s. You cannot pass a `Variant` by reference to a method that expects a string by reference. You can however pass it by value, because then the interpreter will do the conversion for you.

Fix your `Sub xxx` to be `Sub xxx(ByVal x As String)`.

Comment: Alternatively, edit problem vbscript line to `XL.Run "'test.xls'!xxx",  strFolder & vbNullString` which will coerce to `String`.

Comment: Alternatively, enclose the variable in parentheses, `XL.Run "'test.xls'!xxx", (strFolder)`, which will do the same.

Comment: +1 good stuff - several alternatives. I like VB Script files  - although pretty sure I don't use them enough as I get the feeling I could do a lot more with them.

Comment: before seeing this answer I'd amended xxx to `Sub xxx(x As Variant)` but I suspect the above are better solutions